# Labels of the examples in xlistn (gb4e): Showing two numbers

Tags: numbering, linguistics, gb4e

I use the `gb4e` package for numbering examples and I use the `xlistn` environment. I would like that the labels of the items in an `xlistn` environment show the number of examples (`{exe}`) that they belong to and their individual number (`\ex`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex test
    \begin{xlistn}
        \ex test a
        \ex test b
        \ex test c
    \end{xlistn}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

The MWE creates

[image: output of code]

and I would like to have it like this:

```
(1) test
1.1. test a
1.2. test b
1.3. test c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

A more "official" way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\counterwithin{xnumii}{xnumi}
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex test
    \begin{xlistn}
        \ex test a
        \ex test b
        \ex test c
    \end{xlistn}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
    \ex test
    \begin{xlistn}
        \ex test a
        \ex test b
        \ex test c
    \end{xlistn}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Old answer:

Please don't accept it. Just use it until find the correct way. I had no the time to read the documentation. Just a fast fix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\makeatletter
\def\thexnumii{\@xsi{xnumi}.\@xsi{xnumii}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex test
    \begin{xlistn}
        \ex test a
        \ex test b
        \ex test c
    \end{xlistn}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
    \ex test
    \begin{xlistn}
        \ex test a
        \ex test b
        \ex test c
    \end{xlistn}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!